# Yii framework 2.0 asDate() 1 hour earlier

Tags: php, date-format, yii2, formatter

Working with Yii framework 2.0 I get records from my database. In each table I have a column named ***created_at***. Let's say ***created_at = '2015-12-25 01:00:00'***. I use the following Yii formatter.

```
Yii::$app->formatter->asDate($model->created, 'php:d-m-Y h:i:s');
```

The result is: ***25-12-2015 02:00:00***. It is 1 hour earlier. I don't know why. What should I configure to fix this?

Comment: Check you php.ini file for a correct timezone.

Answer (score 1):

@Soju: I have tried your solution. I needed to change your answer a little bit since it solves the problem with the following configuration.

```
'components' => [
    'formatter' => [
         'defaultTimeZone' => 'Europe/Paris',
    ],
],
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set formatter [defaultTimeZone](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-i18n-formatter.html#$defaultTimeZone-detail) and [timeZone](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-i18n-formatter.html#$timeZone-detail) in your components config, for example if you store `UTC` in your database and want to display `Europe/Paris` :

```
'components' => [
    'formatter' => [
        'defaultTimeZone' => 'UTC',
        'timeZone' => 'Europe/Paris',
   ],
],
```

Read more : http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-output-formatter.html#time-zones

Comment: @sojo it does not help. Any other solutions?

Comment: Hi soju - is it  possible to add a output format in the formatter for example dd/mm/YY to display the date globally in desired format or this only works for saving to DB. As I have tried Your suggestion but still the display date I am getting is YY/mm/dd

Comment: @Pawan: If I understand your question correctly, you should convert your date from 'dd/mm/YY/ into 'dd-mm-YY'  and then use this line of code: Yii::$app->formatter->asDate($model->created_at, 'php:Y/m/d'); Because 'dd/mm/YY' is not a valid value for being used in Yii 2 asDate() method.